# Retrieve a date from xml tags in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, date-formatting

I have XML tags in a python list like:

`date_list = [<day>15</day>, <month>10</month>, <year>2020</year>]`

How do I extract the date in the `DD-MM-YYYY` format in Python?

Comment: Are the tags in list guaranteed to be in that order?

Comment: So the list items are Tag objects, not strings? Then you can extract the inner text with `tag_object.contents[0]`. See also answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_list = ['<day>15</day>', '<month>10</month>', '<year>2020</year>']

new_date = []

for elem in date_list:
    new_date.append(elem.split(">")[1].split("<")[0])

new_date = "-".join(new_date)

print (new_date)
```

Output:

```
15-10-2020
```

Comment: How about the tags? Treat the tags as a tag. You have splitted it by > and <.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: <day> </day> , <month></month>, are xml Tags. I want to trat them like a Tag. I will be doing this for many xml files.

Comment: So please review your question, which is then not appropriate. My answer answers your question otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If the tags don't always have the same order you can use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the tags and text content

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
date_list = ['<day>15</day>', '<month>10</month>', '<year>2020</year>']
# create an empty dict
a_date_dict = {}
for date_tag in date_list:
    # parse the string to an ElementTree
    el = ET.fromstring(date_tag)
    # extract data
    a_date_dict[el.tag] = int(el.text)
# at this stage you can output the string
print('{day}-{month}-{year}'.format(**a_date_dict))
# or create a date object
from datetime import date
a_date = date(**a_date_dict)

# Or if you like oneliners and use python 3.8
a_date = date(**{(b:=ET.fromstring(a)).tag:int(b.text) for a in date_list})
```

If the items in `date_list` are Tag objects from Beautiful Soup library then you should be able to use the `contents` attribute

```py
print('{}-{}-{}'.format(*[a.contents[0] for a in date_list]))
```